# Creating an Autoware Vector Map from CARLA Point Cloud Map

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running Autoware (1.12.0) with Carla (0.9.5) using a ROS bridge.
The bridge works fine, but the agent does not avoid obstacles. LiDAR Euclidean clustering detects objects and passes them on to the costmap generator. The costmap generator however does not have any output. I suspect that the problem is the missing vector map.

Therefore I tried to create a verctor map based on the point cloud map, using Autowares Vector Map Builder (https://tools.tier4.jp/feature/vector_map_builder/). But when I try to upload the Carla PCD file nothing happens. Apparently the Vector Map Builder can not import binary compressed PCD files.

This error appears in the console of the Vector Map Builder

```
THREE.PCDLoader: binary_compressed files are not supported
```

Is there a way to import binary compressed files, or a way to uncompress the file?

Thanks for yours support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330943/creating-an-autoware-vector-map-from-carla-point-cloud-map/) by [udeto](https://answers.ros.org/users/44010/udeto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Deepak63](https://answers.ros.org/users/34188/deepak63/) on 2019-11-04**:
Hi udeto,

Just wanted get your feedback.
I'm trying something similar with Carla.

Were you able to create vector map for any Carla Towns?
What was your experience?

Did the agent avoid obstacles after using vector map?

Thanks

**Comment by [sneibus](https://answers.ros.org/users/51953/sneibus/) on 2020-12-04**:
Hi have you managed to do this as i'm in the same boat now trying to generate a vector map from carla town pcd using the vector map builder yet it doesn't import it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Vector map tool can only read ascii.
So, you should convert by using pcl_tools.
It is a command line tools for pcl.

---

Originally posted by [Masaya Kataoka](https://answers.ros.org/users/41502/masaya-kataoka/) with karma: 111 on 2019-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [udeto](https://answers.ros.org/users/44010/udeto/) on 2019-08-18**:
Thank you! Converting using pcl_tool worked!

**Comment by [sneibus](https://answers.ros.org/users/51953/sneibus/) on 2020-12-04**:
hi can you please get me the steps to use pcl tools ?